# Read\Write\Change MySql Table from asp.net list view

Tags: c#, asp.net, mysql, webforms

so, i am building a new website for my brother and it seems that i need to use MySql for him.

In ASP.NET there is a list view item, that you can choose from which DB is will take the info and you can `Read` \ `Write` \ `Change` \ `Delete` with a click of a `button`.

any one here know how can i do that with `MySql` ? and not mssql.. i know how to use `DataBases`, i just didnt ever worked with MySql and i will be thankfull for anyone who will help me.

Thanks again! alon.. :)

Comment: might want to add a mysql tag as well.

Comment: do u want us to help u out with how to use mysql database with asp.net?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a general approach to do basic operations with mysql database. I assume that you know how to setup your mysql database. if not you can find many info about it on google. I also assumed that you have a table on your mysql database named "table" which has following columns: id, name, address.

```
     // Connection String
     private const string ConnStr = 
     "Driver={MySQL ODBC 3.51 Driver};Server=localhost;" + 
     "Database=test;uid=root;pwd=;option=3";
     // DataBinding

     private void BindDataGrid()
     {
         using(OdbcConnection con = new OdbcConnection(ConnStr))
         using(OdbcCommand cmd = 
         new OdbcCommand("SELECT * FROM Sample", con))
         {
             con.Open();
             DataGrid1.DataSource = cmd.ExecuteReader(
                CommandBehavior.CloseConnection | 
                CommandBehavior.SingleResult);
             DataGrid1.DataBind();
         }
     }


     // Insert Operation
     private void InsertInfo()
     {
         if(CheckIsAddNameValid())
         {
             HtmlTable2.Visible = false;

             using(OdbcConnection con = new OdbcConnection(ConnStr))
             using(OdbcCommand cmd = new OdbcCommand("INSERT INTO sample" + 
                            "(name, address) VALUES (?,?)", con))
             {
                 cmd.Parameters.Add("@name", OdbcType.VarChar, 
                                    255).Value = TextBox3.Text.Trim();
                 cmd. Parameters.Add("@address", OdbcType.VarChar, 
                                     255).Value = TextBox4.Text.Trim();

                 con.Open();
                 cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                 BindDataGrid();
             }
         }
     }


     // Update Operation
     private void UpdateInfo(int id, string name, string address)
     {
         using(OdbcConnection con = new OdbcConnection(ConnStr))
         using(OdbcCommand cmd = new OdbcCommand("UPDATE sample " + 
                           "SET name = ?, address = ? WHERE ID = ?", con))
         {
             cmd.Parameters.Add("@name", OdbcType.VarChar, 255).Value = name;
             cmd.Parameters.Add("@address", 
                   OdbcType.VarChar, 255).Value = address;
             cmd.Parameters.Add("@ID", OdbcType.Int).Value = id;

             con.Open();
             cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
         }
     }

     // Update Operation
     private void DeleteInfo(int id)
     {
         using(OdbcConnection con = new OdbcConnection(ConnStr))
         using(OdbcCommand cmd = new OdbcCommand("DELETE " + 
                  "FROM sample WHERE ID = ?", con))
         {
             cmd.Parameters.Add("@ID", OdbcType.Int).Value = id;

             con.Open();
             cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
         }
     }
```

if you do not have a table on your database use this script to create the database in this example:

```
CREATE TABLE sample ( 
    id         int AUTO_INCREMENT NOT NULL,
    name       varchar(45) NOT NULL,
    address    varchar(45) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY(id)
)
GO
```

BindDataGrid function shows the result of the query in datagrid. In general you can put the result of any query to a list and then bind it to the datagrid with the following code:

```
List<string> AllStudents = getAllStudents();
dataGrid1.datasource = AllStudents;
dataGrid1.databind();
```

Answer (score 9):

You first need a connector which you can find [here](http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/net/)

Then instead of using `System.Data` classes use the one you just downloaded. They are the same classes, but the only difference is that they are for MySQL.

Furthermore if you want to write MySQL queries, well they are pretty much the same as in MSSQL. Here are some examples:

**Read:**

```
SELECT id, value FROM table
WHERE id = 16;
```

**Write:**

```
INSERT INTO table(id, value)
VALUES (1,'Bob'),(2,'Betty');
```

**Change:**

```
UPDATE table
SET id = 7
WHERE id = 16;
```

**Delete:**

```
DELETE FROM table
WHERE id = 7;
```

And in your C# code you just need to use 3-4 classes to work with the database. Since I don't want to make this a wall of text, you can read more about those classes [here](http://www.homeandlearn.co.uk/csharp/csharp_s12p5.html) , unless you are familiar enough with those.

Answer (score 1):

ASP.Net works with database through the [Provider Model](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa479020.aspx). You you have downloaded the ADOconnector for MySql, it should work the same way as how it is with MS SQL, except that you have to use different set of queries specific to MySql.

Answer (score 0):

You might also try looking into the [Entity Framework](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/ef.aspx). It is an object-relational-mapper (ORM) which abstracts the tables of a database into objects that you can easily work with in code. It makes code much more readable and maintainable than hardcoding SQL strings (as some of the other answers suggest).

The Entity Framework is Microsoft's recommended solution. You can use it with the MySQL connector that Bosak pointed out.

[NHibernate](https://community.jboss.org/wiki/NHibernateForNET?_sscc=t)  is another popular ORM you might want to look into.